# Cannot update data in oracle database using java

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, sql-update

I'm trying to update the data from my oracle database using this code.
The program has no error but it display `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`.
Can anyone let me know what does it mean and how can I correct it?

```
String gdta="
  UPDATE CLIENT_DATA SET CLIENT_ADDRESS4 = 'SELANGOR' 
    WHERE CLIENT_ADDRESS4 = 68100 BATU CAVES SELANGOR D.E. 
UNION 
  UPDATE CLIENT_DATA SET CLIENT_ADDRESS4 = 'SELANGOR' 
    WHERE CLIENT_ADDRESS4 = 47100 PUCHONG,SELANGORUNION 
  UPDATE CLIENT_DATA SET CLIENT_ADDRESS4 = 'SELANGOR'
    WHERE CLIENT_ADDRESS4 = 47100 PUCHONG";
```

Comment: I formatted the code to make the problem visible, of course this wont compile.

Comment: TQ for formatting code...easier to read...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't combine update statements in a union statement. Also it looks like you need to quote the client_address4 values.

Try running your SQL command in a SQL client before trying it in java and see if it works.

I think you need to execute multiple statements, instead of a single one, like this:

```
String gdta="UPDATE CLIENT_DATA SET CLIENT_ADDRESS4 = 'SELANGOR' WHERE CLIENT_ADDRESS4 = '68100 BATU CAVES SELANGOR D.E.'";
String gdta2="UPDATE CLIENT_DATA SET CLIENT_ADDRESS4 = 'SELANGOR' WHERE CLIENT_ADDRESS4 = '47100 PUCHONG,SELANGOR'";
String gdta3="UPDATE CLIENT_DATA SET CLIENT_ADDRESS4 = 'SELANGOR' WHERE CLIENT_ADDRESS4 = '47100 PUCHONG'";
```

or, use a single statement with an in-clause:

```
String gdta="UPDATE CLIENT_DATA SET CLIENT_ADDRESS4 = 'SELANGOR' WHERE CLIENT_ADDRESS4 in ('68100 BATU CAVES SELANGOR D.E.', '47100 PUCHONG,SELANGOR', '47100 PUCHONG')";
```

Comment: TQ so much...I've already tried it and it works...really appreciate it!!